# OAuth2 for PHP REST web service security

Tags: php, web-services, rest, oauth-2.0

We are working on a PHP REST web service in our web app. Web service returns output in JSON format. Currently, anybody can view the web service's output from a URL. For example;

https://www.example.com/services/contacts/1000

Using above URL, anybody can view contact details for contact id 1000.

We have an authentication system in web app which uses simple email/password combination.

How can we use oauth2 for authentication for PHP REST web service? If I am correct, this has nothing to do with Google.

Comment: There are a lot of OAuth2 libraries in PHP to protect your API.
Take a look at [those libraries on Github](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=oauth2+server&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Usually OAuth2 providers offers 4 authentication flows to use:

- Authorization Code,
- Implicit,
- Resource Owner Password Credentials and
- Client Credentials

If you want more details, you can read [this nice post](http://alexbilbie.com/2013/02/a-guide-to-oauth-2-grants/) with explanation.

The first flow - **Authorization Code** - is the perfect to use with web server applications (like you, using server side code with PHP).

You'll exchange data with the OAuth2 provider inside your PHP script using the [cURL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to send and read sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any server side library for oauth2 provider?

Comment: Based in other similar question, [Is there a simple OAuth2 client for php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15028878/is-there-a-simple-oauth2-client-for-php), there is [PHPoAuthLib](https://github.com/Lusitanian/PHPoAuthLib). Additionally if your goal is just import contacts, you can use [CloudSponge.com](http://www.cloudsponge.com). Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.